# XMonad network or command line api?

Tags: xmonad

I would like XMonad to switch workspaces in response to a network event (or, alternatively, a command line event since I can write another program to handle the network) rather than a keyboard event.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Hooks-ServerMode.html

It seems you can send 'XServer' events to it. Alternatively maybe https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool might be simpler and sufficient.